# Find differences between table entries in Sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table which contains host system information for a bunch of servers. Every month a script will add hosts and system information to the table with a new entry date. The same server may have multiple entries, each with a different entry date. What I would like to do is use queries to find differences rather than having to pull the data and munch it programmatically. I have 2 main queries I'd like to do:

1. Find hostnames that have been added and dropped between data entry dates. Every month some servers are new, and some are gone compared to last month. How do I find these hostnames?
2. Sometimes certain values change for the host data between entry dates, installed java versions being an example. Can I query for rows where a certain value has changed between entry dates?

The table name is hostdata, with fields: hostname TEXT, os TEXT, javaversions TEXT, entrydate TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use EXISTS with a subquery. This will return new hosts:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM hostdata
   WHERE entrydate = 'thismonth'
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM hostdata AS last
                     WHERE entrydate = 'lastmonth'
                       AND last.hostname = hostdata.hostname)
   ```

   (To get dropped hosts, exchange the month values.)

   However, using a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) might be simpler:

   ```
   SELECT hostname
   FROM hostdata
   WHERE entrydate = 'thismonth'
   EXCEPT
   SELECT hostname
   FROM hostdata
   WHERE entrydate = 'lastmonth'
   ```
2. This is typically done by joining the table with itself, i.e., joining last month's data with this month's data:

   ```
   SELECT last.hostname,
          last.os,
          last.javaversions,
          this.javaversions
   FROM hostdata AS last
   JOIN hostdata AS this ON last.entrydate = 'lastmonth'
                        AND this.entrydate = 'thismonth'
                        AND last.hostname = this.hostname
   WHERE last.javaversions <> this.javaversions
   ```

Comment: That is some sql-fu @CL! I've tried them and they do work just as they should. Unfortunately sqlite's performance at doing the queries is so poor that it's proving to be much faster to do more straightforward queries and use python to process the data. Still, once I get a more powerful database working these will be fantastic timesavers, so thanks!